# Jenkins build failed with stripe Could not determine the dependencies of task ':stripe:check'

Tags: android, jenkins, kotlin, jenkins-plugins, stripe-payments

I was trying to build an android apk using Jenkins but I am stuck with one failure message -

```
app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation 
    processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 
'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.0'.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':stripe:check'.
 Task with path 'checkstyle' not found in project ':stripe'.
```

I have added a third party module stripe in my project and in app level gradle file entry is -

```
implementation project(':stripe')
```

I don't know what's wrong is going on build with jenkins is failing all the time.

Note- Below is my stripe's gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
// make sure this line comes *after* you apply the Android plugin
apply plugin: 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount'

assemble.dependsOn('lint')
check.dependsOn('checkstyle')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing below line from stripe's gradle and replacing all the **app: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies** to **kapt** , Jenkins is generating build successfully.

```
check.dependsOn('checkstyle')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using kotlin compiler and in kotlin we use "kapt" instead of "annotationProcessor". Check your "Stripe" project and changed gradle accordingly.

Comment: Before I was using one with annotationProcessor, after the warning I removed it from gradle file. But problem still exists.